# What is the reason of producing *spark* in the volcanic reaction (decomposition of ammonium dichromate)?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, photochemistry, decomposition

In a scientific demonstration of volcanic eruption(decomposition of ammonium dichromate), the green chromium(III) oxide produces an orange spark to mimic the eruption of lava from a volcano.

I would like to know how the spark is produced. Is it due to the release of photon when the excited state returns to the ground state?

Answer (score 6):

The mechanism of spark shining is the same as the mechanism of the orange glow in the core of the "volcano" - [thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation) of solid bodies.

Sparks are just dust particles of mostly Chromium(III) oxide, going upwards due intense thermal convection and by local mechanical effects of self-burning of crystals.

Comment: To prove that point, use a diffraction grating or hand-held spectroscope -- if the spectrum is continuous, it's thermal, and if there are lines, then I'd be excited to see the results of that experiment -- post it here as an answer.

Comment: Sure. Send me the device.

Comment: That comment was for the OP ;-) BTW, hand spectroscopes are ~US$2.5 at Amazon and AliExpress.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It was hard to imply without the explicit user reference. :-) // The point is, sparks of any kind are not gas based to have a line spectrum.

Comment: P.S. Obviously except electric arcs and similar, that are rather a plasma

Comment: And thermoluminescence in spark particles, which also has peaks: https://www.edinst.com/photoluminescence-thermoluminescence-of-phosphors/ BTW, not everything radiates as a black body, just to put that in the limelight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150270/discussion-between-poutnik-and-drmoishe-pippik).